# How can I set min/max of the x-axis in Rickshaw / D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rickshaw

I want to show a linear graph of time-based data for 'today'. At noon, only half of the graph would be populated as series doesn't contain more data. How can I make rickshaw display the full chart instead of just the timeframe with existing data?

Comment: I know it's kinda late now! But if you are still stuck with this. Just put up some code, I will have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and solved it by adding `null` data points with the desired minimum and maximum x-value:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<div id="x_axis"></div>
<script>
var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
    element: document.getElementById('chart'), 
    width: 500,
    height: 200,
    renderer: 'line',
    series: [
        {   data: [         
                { x: -5, y: null},
                { x: 10, y: null},
            ]
        },   
        {   color: 'steelblue',         
            data: [
                { x: 0, y: 40 },
                { x: 1, y: 49 },
                { x: 2, y: 38 },
                { x: 3, y: 30 },
                { x: 4, y: 32 } ]
        }
    ]    
});  

var x_ticks = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X({
    graph: graph,
    orientation: 'bottom',
    element: document.getElementById('x_axis'),
    pixelsPerTick: 100,
});

graph.render();
</script>
```

This shows a graph with an x-axis from -5 to 10, with data only between 0 and 4.